# Selecting a checkbox present in a grid using UIAutomation

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

Selecting a checkbox present in a grid using UIAutomation. Below code returns invalidpattern for invoke pattern:

```
AutomationElement mainGrid = appElement1.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "ReadinessTestList"));
// find the grid in the window 
if (mainGrid != null)
 {

    MessageBox.Show("inside the grid");

    // select just the first cell 
    var item = mainGridPattern.GetItem(0, 0);
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(item));
    //item.SetFocus();

    AutomationElement FirstCheckBox = GetTextElement(item, "SystemNameCheckBox");

    if (FirstCheckBox != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(FirstCheckBox));
        TogglePattern SelectedFirstCheckBox = FirstCheckBox.GetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern) as TogglePattern;
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(SelectedFirstCheckBox));

        ToggleState FirstCheckBxState = SelectedFirstCheckBox.Current.ToggleState;
        string try2 = Convert.ToString(FirstCheckBxState);
        MessageBox.Show(try2);

        //FirstCheckBxState.On;

        if (FirstCheckBxState != ToggleState.On) // not on? click it
        {            
            InvokePattern invokefirstCheckBox = (InvokePattern)FirstCheckBox.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            invokefirstCheckBox.Invoke();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [toggle pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750424(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) instead of the invoke pattern for a checkbox.

```
 TogglePattern tpToggle = (TogglePattern)aeElement.GetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern);
 tpToggle.Toggle();
```

Also you should use inspect.exe which can be found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86 after installing [windows development kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx). This tool will allow you to see the supported patterns of what you are attempting to automate.